# Can anyone tell me where can I find and example of a lazy listview with sections?

Tags: android, listview, lazy-evaluation, sections

Can anyone tell me where can I find and example of a lazy listview with sections?

it would be perfect one version of
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/
with sections incorporated.

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by sections? Overriding an adapter with getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of that:
[lazy-listview](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)